# The hypothesis of a kind of life for archetypes of particular patterns in human societies

Tags: jung

Can concepts such as the [archetype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungian_archetypes) (ancient patterns) in [Jung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Jung)'s theory have a life in human societies, and if so, can these concepts become contaminated and diseased?

A look at  religion introduces it like a virus mentioned in [Richard Dawkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dawkins)' talk.

A kind of life that may be a kind of clever life resulting from evolution among members of one species, perhaps Jung 's work can somehow channel this into science.

For example, can a concept like God or Satan have a life in this domain (within the collective subconscious of humans) and become contaminated by the overuse and the pathogenic look of humans, and therefore whether systems like this have a collective subconscious? Defense systems (referred to by Freud) can be upgradable. And can the poems of individuals such as [sohrab sepehri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sohrab_Sepehri) or [Mansur Al-Hallaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansur_Al-Hallaj) about God and Satan in this respect be somehow related to the question of the evolution and enhancement of the defense systems of these subconscious components?